# adding columns to dataframe based on the values in existing column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, extract

I'm working in Rstudio and have a data frame  similiar to the following:

```
Favorite<-c("Apple","Lemon","Orange","Salat","Onion", "Apple","Strawberry","Celery","Blueberry","Sweetpotatoes","Strawberry",
                "Oragne","Celery","Sweetpotatoes","Onion","Blueberry","Strawberry","Salad")
PersonID<-c(67,82,67,21,02,12,90,23,65,32,44,67,56,77,30,198,20,99)
all_Data<-data.frame(PersonID,Favorite)

> head(all_Data)
  PersonID Favorite
1       67    Apple
2       82    Lemon
3       67   Orange
4       21    Salat
5        2    Onion
6       12    Apple
```

I want to add 3 more column and they should  contains the following:

If a row in  all_Data$Favorite is Apple or Blueberry then all_Data$Country = Ireand, all_Data$Continent= Europe and all_Data$city=Belfast

If a row in  all_Data$Favorite is Strawberry then all_Data$Country = Holland, all_Data$Continent= Europe and all_Data$city=Emmen

If a row in  all_Data$Favorite is Lemon or Orange then all_Data$Country = France, all_Data$Continent= Europe and all_Data$city=Menton

If a row in  all_Data$Favorite is Salad or Onion then all_Data$Country = Sweeden, all_Data$Continent= Europe and all_Data$city=Malmoe

If a row in  all_Data$Favorite is Lemon or Orange then all_Data$Country = France, all_Data$Continent= Europe and all_Data$city=Menton

If a row in  all_Data$Favorite is Sweetpotatoes then all_Data$Country = USA, all_Data$Continent= America and all_Data$city=Verona

If a row in  all_Data$Favorite is Celery then all_Data$Country = Germany, all_Data$Continent= Europe and all_Data$city=Berlin

```
library(tidyverse)

all_Data |> 
  mutate(ctry_cont = case_when(
    str_detect(Favorite, "Appl|Blueb")  ~ "Ireland|Europe",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Straw")       ~ "Brazillian|South's of America",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Lemon|Orang") ~ "France|Europe",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Salad|Onion") ~ "Sweden|Europe",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Sweetpot")    ~ "United of state|America",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Celery")      ~ "Germany|Europe",
    TRUE                                ~ "Other|Other"
  )) |> 
  separate(ctry_cont, c("country", "continent"))
```

After running the code above I get the following warning and data where we see half of the value of United of Kingdom and United of America. I have also added words with apostrophe since in my original data there are word with apostrophes, but it is also not visible:

```
     PersonID      Favorite    country continent
1        67         Apple    Ireland    Europe
2        82         Lemon     France    Europe
3        67        Orange     France    Europe
4        21         Salat      Other     Other
5         2         Onion     Sweden    Europe
6        12         Apple    Ireland    Europe
7        90    Strawberry Brazillian     South
8        23        Celery    Germany    Europe
9        65     Blueberry    Ireland    Europe
10       32 Sweetpotatoes     United        of
11       44    Strawberry Brazillian     South
12       67        Oragne      Other     Other
13       56        Celery    Germany    Europe
14       77 Sweetpotatoes     United        of
15       30         Onion     Sweden    Europe
16      198     Blueberry    Ireland    Europe
17       20    Strawberry Brazillian     South
18       99         Salad     Sweden    Europe

    Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 5 rows [7, 10, 11, 14, 17].
```

I also tried to add sep=""at the last step of the code. it gives an error.

```
separate(ctry_cont, c("country", "continent"), sep="")
```

Comment: You should consider making another table that has Favorite, Country Continet and City then do a left_join/merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this ...

```r
Favorite <- c(
  "Apple",
  "Lemon",
  "Orange",
  "Salad",
  "Onion",
  "Apple",
  "Strawberry",
  "Celery",
  "Blueberry",
  "Sweetpotatoes",
  "Strawberry",
  "Orange",
  "Celery",
  "Sweetpotatoes",
  "Onion",
  "Blueberry",
  "Strawberry",
  "Salad"
)

PersonID <-
  c(67, 82, 67, 21, 02, 12, 90, 23, 65, 32, 44, 67, 56, 77, 30, 198, 20, 99)

all_Data <- data.frame(PersonID, Favorite)

library(tidyverse)

all_Data |> 
  mutate(ctry_cont = case_when(
    str_detect(Favorite, "Appl|Blueb")  ~ "Ireland, Europe",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Straw")       ~ "Holland, Europe",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Lemon|Orang") ~ "France, Europe",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Salad|Onion") ~ "Sweden, Europe",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Sweetpot")    ~ "United States, North America",
    str_detect(Favorite, "Celery")      ~ "Germany, Europe",
    TRUE                                ~ "Other, Other"
  )) |> 
  separate(ctry_cont, c("country", "continent"), sep = ", ")
#>    PersonID      Favorite       country     continent
#> 1        67         Apple       Ireland        Europe
#> 2        82         Lemon        France        Europe
#> 3        67        Orange        France        Europe
#> 4        21         Salad        Sweden        Europe
#> 5         2         Onion        Sweden        Europe
#> 6        12         Apple       Ireland        Europe
#> 7        90    Strawberry       Holland        Europe
#> 8        23        Celery       Germany        Europe
#> 9        65     Blueberry       Ireland        Europe
#> 10       32 Sweetpotatoes United States North America
#> 11       44    Strawberry       Holland        Europe
#> 12       67        Orange        France        Europe
#> 13       56        Celery       Germany        Europe
#> 14       77 Sweetpotatoes United States North America
#> 15       30         Onion        Sweden        Europe
#> 16      198     Blueberry       Ireland        Europe
#> 17       20    Strawberry       Holland        Europe
#> 18       99         Salad        Sweden        Europe
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I tried using mutate_at since it can be use to add mutiple column, but I pretty sure that i'm using it wrong

Comment: I've added a way you could incorporate continent.  You could do likewise with city.

Comment: `mutate_at` changes multiple *existing* variables (and it has been superseded now by `mutate` with `across`).

Comment: As KU99 suggested, the other option is to create a separate reference table and then join them. I notice some of your input data has typos, e.g. "Oragne", so these would need to be cleaned up first (which is often a good thing to do).

Comment: My input data is not the original data. It is just similiar to my data. Your suggestion worked fine except if a value is not one word. For example if one of the value in the Country column was "United of State" then it does not work properly.

Comment: can you show what you tried with the error? It may be that you need to add an explicit sep= “” argument to the separate function if it’s treating a space or | as the separator. Take a look at the help for the separate function. I’m guessing that’s the problem without seeing your error.

Comment: I added the warning message that I got in the post above.

Comment: I've updated the suggestion with an explicit separator.  I've used ", ". You'll see in the ?separate documentation you can choose what you want. By default it uses multiple options, hence the need to be explicit if your labels contain spaces and other characters.